# Where do I start with $\sim((P\wedge Q)\vee \sim(P\vee Q))$?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

can anyone tell me in a table form how to start with this 
 $\sim((P\wedge Q)\vee \sim(P\vee Q))$ I am confused on how to do this part $\sim(P\wedge Q)$, which one we do first, inside brackets or outside?

Comment: in your formula there is a parenthes missing; written as : ~((P^Q)v~(PvQ) we assume that the "scope" of the outermost "~" sign is the all formula : $\lnot ((P \land Q) \lor \lnot (P \lor Q))$. In this case, you have to move it "inside" with De Morgan's laws.

Comment: so u mean we have to do brackets first then apply ~ sign

Comment: It works both ways. If you start with $\lnot$, by "De Morgan 1" into [Boolean algenra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) you will get : $\lnot (P∧Q) \land (P∨Q)$; then apply "De Morgan 2" to get : $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (P \lor Q)$. In the other way you will first "distribute" $\lor$ over $\land$ , but you must not forget $\lnot$ ...

Comment: @amWhy: Watch out for that sneaky `l` key.

Comment: What do you mean by "table form"? Do you mean truth tables, or do you mean a particular tabular format for writing syllogisms involving formulas of logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lnot ((P\wedge Q)\vee \lnot(P\vee Q))$$

Which "negation" $\lnot$ you apply first doesn't matter with respect to the end result. But outer, then inner is less work.

Using DeMorgan's with respect to the "outermost" negation sign, and then the inner one:

$$\begin{align} \lnot ((P\wedge Q)\vee \lnot (P\vee Q))&\equiv \lnot (P\land Q) \land \lnot \lnot (P\lor Q)\\ \\ &\equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (P\lor Q)\end{align}$$

Using DeMorgan's first with respect to the innermost application, and then the outer one:

$$\begin{align} \lnot ((P\wedge Q)\vee \lnot (P\vee Q))& \equiv \lnot ((P \land Q) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q))\\ \\ &\equiv \lnot (P \land Q) \land \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)\\ \\ & \equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)\land (\lnot \lnot P \lor \lnot \lnot Q) \\ \\ &\equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (P \lor Q)\end{align}$$